# Angular and materialize datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc, materialize

How to get selected date from materialize datepicker?

This is my input:

```
<div class="input-field col s3">
   <input id="buyDate" class="datepicker" type="text" name="buyDate" 
   ng-model="buyDate" materialize-date-picker readonly>
</div>
```

And my script:

```
$scope.SaveButton = function(){
      var postRequest = $http({
          method: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost:5000/licenses",
          dataType: 'json',
          data : { 
             name: $scope.name,  
             count: $scope.count,  
             buyDate: $scope.buyDate,  
             licenseType: $scope.licenseType.licenseTypeId 
          },
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"}
      });

      postRequest.error(function (data, status){
          $window.aler(data.Message);
      })
  }
```

Comment: Is it AngularJS or Angular 2+?

Comment: It's AngularJS.

Comment: read this https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_databinding.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for but you can

```
var dateStr = document.getElementById("buyDate").value;
var dateObj = Date.parse(dateStr);
```

And then dateObj will be a datetime object corresponding to that date. I don't know angular so someone familiar with it might be able to give you a more angular-y answer but as far as js goes this should work.